# Apple watch os2 simulator afnetwork request is very slow for some reason

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, apple-watch, simulator

The following is my Code I use for both Apple Watch and Apple Watch OS2. My apple watch os2 simulator takes 3 to 4 times longer to do the same request than my Apple watch os1. I am not sure why this is. I've tried googling the answer but no result. Any information is appreciated.

```
- (IBAction)syncForms:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"CLICK");
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

    [manager GET:@"http://requestb.in/1i1lhxz"
      parameters:nil
         success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
             NSLog(@"SUCCESS");
         }
         failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
             NSLog(@"FAILURE");
         }];
  }
```

Edit: I've also tried this

```
 NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://requestb.in/1i1lhxz"];
    //type your URL u can use initWithFormat for placeholders
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];  //use NSURLSession class
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];

    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *task = [session downloadTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    }];
    [task resume];
```

However, the same result. So I think it can't be afnetworking.

Comment: I have the same issue. It seems request on watch side slower than iPhone.

Comment: Im running into the same issue. How can I put the watch extension back onto the phone so it runs there and runs faster? I want to watch OS 1 speed!